# R: Storing function symbols for later reuse and making a global "undebug()"

Tags: r, debugging, symbols

I would like to write a wrapper for the `debug()` function so that I can remove all debugging flag when needed.

For functions in the search path it is simple.

```
.debugged <- NULL
debug.wrapper <- function(fun){
    f <- deparse(substitute(fun))
    .debugged <<- unique(c(.debugged, f))
    debug(f)    
}
debug.wrapper.off <- function() {
    z=sapply(.debugged, undebug)
    .debugged <<- NULL    
}
```

It works because I can use the character version of the function symbol.

```
f <-  function() print("hello")
debug.wrapper(f)
isdebugged(f)
# [1] TRUE
debug.wrapper.off()
isdebugged(f)
# [1] FALSE
```

Anyway with namespaces it does not work:

```
debug.wrapper(tools:::psnice)
# Error in debug(f) could not find function "tools:::psnice"
```

Also:

```
debug(substitute(tools:::psnice))
# Error in debug(fun, text, condition) : argument must be a function
```

How can I store the function symbols for later reuse?

Comment: Try `match.fun`, it accepts both.  Changing the line `f <- deparse(substitute(fun))` to `f <- match.fun(fun)` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @RichScriven: Thanks,  I succeeded in different way, as I realised concatenating function symbols does not involve making function copies.

Answer (score 1):

### Note

It seems that concatenating function symbols creates a sort of "soft pointer" rather than a copy, that is:

```
x <- c(tools:::psnice, identity)
```

Taking the first function, we get:

```
x[[1]]    
# function (pid = Sys.getpid(), value = NA_integer_) 
# {
#     res <- .Call(ps_priority, pid, value)
#     if (is.na(value)) 
#         res
#     else invisible(res)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x00000000189f1f80>
# <environment: namespace:tools>
```

The bytecode and environment are the same as with `tools:::psnice`.
Therefore  `un/debug(x[[1]])` is like `un/debug(tools:::psnice)`

### Solution

Given the note above, the solution is trivial.   Debug wrappers are defined as:

```
.debugged <- NULL
debug.wrapper <- function(fun){    
    .debugged <<- unique(c(.debugged, fun))
    debug(fun)    
}
debug.wrapper.off <- function() {
    z=sapply(.debugged, undebug)
    .debugged <<- NULL    
}
```

Using them brings:

```
f <-  function() print("hello")
debug.wrapper(f)
debug.wrapper(tools:::psnice)
isdebugged(f)
# [1] TRUE
isdebugged(tools:::psnice)
# [1] TRUE
debug.wrapper.off()
isdebugged(f)
isdebugged(tools:::psnice)
.debugged
# NULL
```

Of course, one can add conditions to manage the case when passed `fun` is a string.

Thanks to @Rich Scriven, who gave useful insights.